# Active noise control barrier at tunnel openings in undergroundsubways

Tags: noise-reduction, acoustics, active-noise-control

I know that Noise cancellation never works on scales larger than the sound's wavelength.but,at underground stations during the train arrival time we experience a lot of disturbance which sometimes make announcements and random talk to be noisy.assuming a free field condition, which is valid locally in a large open space.ignoring the reverberant field . The focus is on reducing the SPL near the tunnel opening, say at the platform on 10m distance.so my question is,is it possible to reduce the tunnel boom and added ambiend noise using a combined active and passive cotrollers?

Answer (score 1):

Tunnels should have easy to calculate resonant frequencys so you could try helmholtz absobers.

Comment: Hi Tobias, how would that work exactly? fitting a giant a helmholtz unit (i think it's called a resonator btw) would be quite a hassle i guess..

Comment: Yeah they are called resonators!. I think they could be placed directly at the entrance to the stations. So they reduce the boom the trains "pushes" in front of him. Also some high frequency damping would make sense right at the edge of the tunnel. There the noise is pretty "compact" so absorbed would have a big impact.

Answer (score 0):

active won't do much good for you over a big space - too many variables.  Acoustic damping is likely to be the best solution.  Kill it at the source.